# How do i do a "tweaked" VLOOKUP?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vlookup

So here is the problem: I have 3 lists (adjacent columns) in a spreadsheet.

1. The 1st list contains the values I am searching for
2. The 2nd list contains the first half of table array which I am searching
3. The 3rd list contains the second half of the table array which I am searching

What I would like to do is search the second list for the values in the first list (this is a normal VLOOKUP so far) but **instead of returning the values in the third list I need to change them to either "1" or "0"**.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In column 3 you can use this -

```
=IF(ISNA(IF(MATCH(B1,A:A,0),1)),0,1)
```

It returns 1 if the value is found, 0 if it isn't.

Or, if you'd rather be smart about it, you can use [Engineer Toast](https://superuser.com/users/348859/engineer-toast)'s formula

```
=IFERROR(1+0*MATCH(B1,A:A,0),0)
```

---

Essentially, the basis is that by using [match](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca?CorrelationId=c7479577-b309-46c8-9226-3ee89d747061&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), you are checking for the value in the list and return an error if it isn't found.

Comment: I like `=IFERROR(1+0*MATCH(B1,A:A,0),0)` only because it uses less functions and is shorter.

Comment: It probably works better, I just ended up starting with the wrong function, taking me down the path I went.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help guys this works perfectly! :)

Comment: You could also use this: `=1-ISNA(MATCH(B1,A:A,0))`....or `=(COUNTIF(A:A,B1)>0)+0`